# shows same id in different buttons. conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, conflict

i'm loading content of  from external html files. page1.html and page2.html. everything is the same except pictures and text. but there is conflict with close button. it closes just page1.html
here is example of my code

```
function close_box() {
    dividid = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
    divid = $('#' + dividid).parents('div').attr('id');
    dividofid = $('#' + divid).parents('div').attr('id');
    alert(dividofid);
    return false;
}
```

and this is html

```
<div id="page1id">
    <div id="danis">
        <div id="close_box"> <a onclick='close_box.call(this);'>page1 close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2id">
    <div id="danik">
        <div id="close_box"> <a onclick='close_box.call(this);'>page2 close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


http://jsfiddle.net/LULrE/3/
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LULrE/3/

Comment: You can change everyyhing to the following.
`alert($(this).closest('[id^="page"]')[0].id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your corrected code:

```
function close_box() {
    var divid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    alert(divid);
    return false;
}
```

The problem with your code was that `dividid` gets `close_box`, but then when you use that id in a selector, it picks the first div with an id of `close_box`, which is the div that corresponds to page1.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LULrE/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Your `id`s on a page need to be unique.  If you need multiple `id`s on the page with the same value on the same page for CSS reasons, use the `class` attribute.

For JS purposes, if you look for a specific `id` on the page, only the first one is being returned.  In your case `$('#' + dividid);` resolves to `$('#close_box');` which returns only the first element it finds.

I would approach your problem like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="page1id" class="closeable">
    <div id="danis">
        <div id="close_box"> <a onclick='close_box.call(this);'>page1 close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2id" class="closeable">
    <div id="danik">
        <div id="close_box"> <a onclick='close_box.call(this);'>page2 close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function close_box() {
    var page_level_div = $(this).closest('.closeable');
    page_level_div.hide()
    return false;
}
```

EDIT:

Last but not least, I would suggest you NOT use onclick handlers in your HTML.  Especially since you are already using jQuery, you could easily rewrite your code like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="page1id" class="closeable">
    <div id="danis">
        <div class="close_box"> <a href="">page1 close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2id" class="closeable">
    <div id="danik">
        <div class="close_box"> <a href="">page2 close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close_box").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.closeable').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: understood. so i must give unique id for all pages even if it's external and not loading at same time

Comment: @bahaS As long as two elements don't exist at the exact same time with the same id, you're ok.